# What did Noh-Varr give to Annie?

Tags: comics, marvel, avengers

We see Noh-Varr give a piece of stone to Annie in Avengers #26.  It starts glowing and levitating in Avengers #27, when Noh-Varr is

> under attack by both sides for betraying both the Avengers and the Kree.

What is this?  Are there any educated guesses that could be made, given it isn't described in the Avengers (despite Annie's repeated questions)?

[image]

Comment: My initial thoughts are it could be several things: piece of a Nega-Band, or something linked to the Supreme Intelligence,  but I'll do some digging when I'm not at work

Answer (score 1):

From [this description](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noh-Varr#cite_ref-16) I'd make an educated guess at part of the Phoenix's essence.

According [to this](http://www.comicvine.com/forums/noh-varr/1631/is-noh-varr-a-bad-guy-now/688935/) it's (part of?) a clipped wing of the Phoenix Force.

2nd source seems more accurate, either way, looks like part of the Phoenix Force.